# Can anyone define UITableView in terms of MVC?

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, uitableview

Can we categorize various delegate & datasource methods of UITableView in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. A UITableView's table view delegate and data source are both part of the controller layer. The data source acts as a mediator which passes data between the view and the model it displays; instructing the table view how many rows to display or updating the model when a user deletes a row. The table view delegate acts as more of a coordinating controller, associating the table view with header and footer views and updating views as editing or selection states change. Take a look at [Types of Cocoa Controller Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW8) for a good overview of the roles controllers are expected to play in Cocoa and iOS apps and how these can be slightly different than the idea of "MVC" in other environments.